# How to get Android device owner's user profile data using Xamarin/C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm building an app for Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and higher, and would like to get the device owner's user profile info such as:

DisplayName, Email, Phone, Job Title, Company, Office Location, Website and Url

I've tried different methods from different Stackoverflow posts that I read, including going to the phone's accounts to querying the user profile (ContactsContract.Profile.ContentUri). No dice. I've checked the permissions for ReadOwnerData and ReadProfile.

Right now I'm querying the Contacts with this code, but the managed query is returning with a count of 0.

```
var c = act.ManagedQuery (ContactsContract.Profile.ContentUri, null, null, null, null);
int count = c.Count;
string[] columnNames = c.GetColumnNames();
bool b = c.MoveToFirst();
int position = c.Position;
if (position == 0) {
    do {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.Length; j++) {
            string columnName = columnNames[j];
            try {
                string columnValue = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(columnName));
            } catch {}
            if (c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex("is_user_profile")) == "1") {
                if (c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex("has_email")) == "1") {
                    //var cEmail = ManagedQuery (ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri, null, ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.HasPhoneNumber + "!=0 AND (" + ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype + "=? OR " + ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype + "=?)", new String[]{ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentItemType, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentItemType, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id }, null);
                    var cEmail = act.ManagedQuery (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.Type + " = ?", new String[]{ c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(BaseColumns.Id)) }, null);
                    string[] columnNamesEmail = cEmail.GetColumnNames();
                    if (cEmail.Count > 0) {
                        cEmail.MoveToFirst();
                        do {
                            sEmail = cEmail.GetString(cEmail.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.Type));
                            //sEmail = cEmail.GetString(cEmail.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.Data));
                            //sEmail = cEmail.GetString(cEmail.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.ContactId));
                        } while (cEmail.MoveToNext());
                    }
                    cEmail.Close();
                }
                if (c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex("has_phone_number")) == "1") {
                    var cPhone = act.ManagedQuery (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = ?", new String[]{ c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(BaseColumns.Id)) }, null);
                    string[] columnNamesPhone = cPhone.GetColumnNames();
                    if (cPhone.Count > 0) {
                        cPhone.MoveToFirst();
                        do {
                            sPhone = cPhone.GetString(cPhone.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type));
                        } while (cPhone.MoveToNext());
                    }
                    cPhone.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    } while (c.MoveToNext());
}
c.Close();
```

This part of the code returns with a count of 0:

```
if (cEmail.Count > 0) {
```

Can someone point out how I can rewrite this query?

```
var cEmail = act.ManagedQuery (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.Type + " = ?", new String[]{ c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(BaseColumns.Id)) }, null);
```

Or should I go back to querying the user profile or accounts? Here's the code I was using for them:

Accounts:

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.Get (Context).GetAccounts ();
foreach (Account acc in accounts) {
    --- can only get DisplayName and ID
}
```

User Profile:

```
var uri = ContactsContract.Profile.ContentUri;

string[] projection = { 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DisplayName, 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.Address,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.Title,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.Company,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.OfficeLocation,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.Url };

var cursor = ManagedQuery (uri, projection, null, null, null);

if (cursor.MoveToFirst ()) {
    do {
        sDisplayName = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [0]));
        sEmail = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [1]));
        sPhone = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [2]));
        sTitle = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [3]));
        sCompany = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [4]));
        sOfficeLocation = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [5]));
        sWebsite = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [6]));


    } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
}
```

Comment: I changed the email query to var cEmail = act.ManagedQuery (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = ?", new String[]{ c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(BaseColumns.Id)) }, null); but still coming up with a count of 0.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am trying to getting user's name and email address?